# SSL to log in, regular http after that... how vulnerable is the data transferred from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I roamed the site for this question using the search engine, and I don't think it's out there. If it is, apologies in advance and feel free to point me to it.

Here is my scenario:

I am setting up a web application, Moodle if anyone is familiar with it, with Apache, MySQL, and php on Windows. Moodle supports enabling SSL for login, but then reverts to regular http after login is established. This is running on an internal network with no connection to the outside world, so no Internet access through this network. All users who use the network have logins, however there are some generic guest type logins with certain restricted privilages. Currently the MySQL database is not encrypted.

My question is this:

If my users do an SSL login, and the system then reverts back to http for the remainder of their session, how vulnerable is the data that is transferred back and forth between the browser interface and the database?

I would perhaps prefer to have all the data encrypted, but I am not sure how bad the performance hit would be to do that, so any suggestions concerning that would be appreciated too. Although I will be extending the functionality in Moodle, I don't necessarily want to have to change it to encrypt everything if already does.

I am new to the world of IT security, and my DBA skills are rusty, so if you give me an answer, type slowly so I can understand! ;)

Thanks in advance!
Carvell

Comment: Wow! That was an astoundingly fast and informative response by all! I am very impressed. I will add a couple more comments below. Thanks all!

Comment: Are you going to even have enough simultaneous users for the performance hit to be worth measuring?  There's probably bigger things to worry about like tuning MySQL and running a PHP opcode cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. The fact that the data in the DB server is not encrypted in no way is a factor in the communication between the User and the Web Server.  It is a concern obviously for communications between the web server and the database server.
2. Your risk point between user and web server is in that packets could be sniffed if a person was able to interject in the middle of the communication chain.  However, this risk is mitigated by the fact that your on an internal network.

Therefore, unless you are VERY concerned about the other people in your organization, you are more than likely ok.  However, if it is really sensitive data, you might do ALL communications via SSL to ensure that it is transmitted securely.  IF you are this concerned, then I would also look at the security of the DB and the communications from DB to webserver.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming though that if the web app only support SSL for the login, it is not as simple as just turning on SSL for everything else?

Comment: Depends on the APP and what it supports.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I would love to be able to select two answers. Both Mitchel's and zombat's were exactly what I was looking for. Mitchel got in a bit quicker zombat, so for that reason I give the nod to him. Thanks all for your great answers. I have a lot to learn in this area, so the information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My concern would be how your authenticated sessions are propagated.

Generally a session works by setting a cookie or appending a session id to any URLs presented by the web site.  Once a log-in has been established, often the credentials aren't needed any more, as a session is then linked to the user and deemed to be authenticated, and the existence of the session itself is proof of a successful authentication.

However, as previous posters have mentioned, local network traffic can be available for sniffing.  If someone sniffed a session id, they could recreate the cookie or urls using the session id, and simply access the site as that session user, even changing the user's password if that option was available.

I would say that your decision here rests on the security of your sessions.  If you have some mitigating factors in place to make sessions difficult to replicate even if a session id is compromised (ie. comparison to ip addresses, etc), or your user accounts are relatively secure from a compromised session (eg. require current password to change account settings), then perhaps SSL after login isn't required.  However, if you have doubts and can afford the performance hit, then having SSL throughout the site will guarantee that your sessions can't be compromised (as far as you can guarantee SSL, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

With no internet access to this network, the only thing that could potentially happen is someone else (who is already on the internal network) snooping on another user's HTTP traffic. If someone were to actually do that, and you aren't using SSL, they could read all the data that your website is sending/receiving from that user. But is that actually a concern?

Comment: It is only a concern because I am in an organization that is on the extreme end of being concerned about such things.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on an internal network turning on SSL for the whole site should not be that bad performance wise, although it is probably unneccesary.

At the very least, you should encrypt the data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

All sensitive data should be encrypted when transferred over an insecure wire. If you just transfer login details over SSL, all your data is still vulnerable to eavesdropping.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data's not encrypted, anybody with sufficient network access (i.e. physical access) can read the data passing back and forth from server to browser and back. As long as everyone who has physical access to the network also has authorization to read the data, you're probably alright. If any of the information is sensitive, and should be restricted to being viewed by a subset of people who have physical access to the network, then you need to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone on your network would be able to see everyone else's traffic with a network packet sniffer like WireShark. The connection between your web server and MySQL is also in cleartext. MySQL may not actually send passwords in cleartext; it may be a hash, for instance.

If you are really trying to be paranoid, you may not need to run your app over HTTPS. There are other lower-level possibilities like IPSec. Since this is an internal network, you can probably get away with implementing this on all workstations.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to add to the above correct responses.  But, one think you can do is use a [Threat Modeling tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd206731.aspx) for your application.  That will inform you on the *types* of threats you are exposing your data to by not using transport level encryption (TLS/SSL).  Once you understand the threats, you can decide on an appropriate risk mitigation plan.